# Last 7 days Unix/Redshift filter not working

Tags: sql, unix, amazon-redshift, epoch

This query is happening in Redshift whose SQL idiosyncrasies drive me crazy.

I have a UNIX epoch timestamp in my table and I need to filter for the most recent seven days. Redshift lacks the `from_unixtime()` function so I've hacked this together. `tb_h` is the UNIX date column. 604800000 is the number of milliseconds in a seven day period.

`"tb_h" >= DATE_PART(epoch, DATEADD(milliseconds, -604800000, DATEADD(day, -1, trunc(getdate()))))`

This workaround doesn't filter on the last seven, it allows all dates through. What's my logical error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you use a more reasonable type for the subtraction?

```
"tb_h" >= DATE_PART(epoch, DATEADD(day, -7, DATEADD(day, -1, CURRENT_DATE)))
```

Second, in Postgres, `epoch` returns the number of seconds -- and I'm not sure if Redshift is the same. If your value is in milliseconds or microseconds, you need to multiply:

```
"tb_h" >= 1000 * DATE_PART(epoch, DATEADD(day, -8, CURRENT_DATE))
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these solutions work, the top one returns all dates and the bottom one returns nothing. I'm going to keep testing these and try to get them working.

Comment: My timestamp is 13 digits, which is in milliseconds

Comment: The issue is that the timestamp field isn't actually a timestamp data type, it's recorded as a BIGINT